# Additional Law Word Problem

Tags: probability

Forgive me if this is really basic:

> Tammy is a general contractor and has submitted two bids for two projects (A and B). The probability of getting project A is 0.65. The probability of getting project B is 0.77. The probability of getting at least one of the projects is 0.90. What is the probability that she will get both projects?

Is this a simple question using the addition law or am I missing something? I calculated that her probability of getting both would be 0.52.

(0.65 + 0.77 - 0.90) = .52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A)=&\,0.65,\\
\mathbb{P}(B)=&\,0.77,\\
\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=&\,0.90,\\
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=&\,\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=0.52.
\end{align*}
Your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0):

P(A or B) = P(A)+P(B) -P(A and B)

Therefore

P(A or B) - P(B) -P(A) = -P(A and B)

with P(A or B) = 0.9
P(A) = 0.65
P(B) = 0.77

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your reasoning. How did you know the 0.9 was project A? Did you just rewrite this to solve for the unknown?

Answer (score 0):

P(A)=0.65
P(B)=0.77
P(A∪B)=0.9
P(A∩B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A∪B)
=0.65+0.77-0.9
=0.52